# Spread tibble as matrix with row names

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, tidyr, tibble

I want to get spreaded `tibble` as matrix with first column as rownames like below:

**Required**

```
        E1         E2
G1  0.5855288 -1.8179560
G2  0.7094660  0.6300986
G3 -0.1093033 -0.2761841
G4 -0.4534972 -0.2841597
G5  0.6058875 -0.9193220
```

**Obtained**

so far got the following

```
            E1         E2
[1,]  0.5855288 -1.8179560
[2,]  0.7094660  0.6300986
[3,] -0.1093033 -0.2761841
[4,] -0.4534972 -0.2841597
[5,]  0.6058875 -0.9193220
```

**Minimum Working Example**

with the given code

```
set.seed(12345)
Y   <- rnorm(10)
Env <- paste0("E", rep(1:2, each = 5))
Gen <- paste0("G", rep(1:5, times = 2))
df1 <- data.frame(Y, Env, Gen)

library(magrittr)
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  tidyr::spread(key =  Env, value = Y) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup() %>%
  dplyr::select(-Gen) %>%
  as.matrix()
```

Comment: Try with `acast` i.e. `reshape2::acast(df1, Gen~Env, value.var = "Y")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we are using `magrittr`, the option would be `set_rownames`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  spread(Env, Y)  %>%
  set_rownames(.$Gen) %>%
  select(-Gen) %>%
  as.matrix
#           E1         E2
#G1  0.5855288 -1.8179560
#G2  0.7094660  0.6300986
#G3 -0.1093033 -0.2761841
#G4 -0.4534972 -0.2841597
#G5  0.6058875 -0.9193220
```

---

It can also be done with `acast` from `reshape2`

```
library(reshape2)
acast(df1, Gen~Env, value.var = "Y")
```

Comment: but how would you put `set_rownames(.$Gen)` in a function, given the non-standard evaluation?

Comment: @sharchaea You can use `column_to_rownames` from `tibble` `f1 <- function(dat, var1, var2, var3){dat %>% pivot_wider(names_from = {{var1}}, values_from = {{var2}}) %>% column_to_rownames(rlang::quo_name(enquo(var3))) %>% as.matrix}; f1(df1, Env, Y, Gen)#
           E1         E2
G1  0.5855288 -1.8179560
G2  0.7094660  0.6300986
G3 -0.1093033 -0.2761841
G4 -0.4534972 -0.2841597
G5  0.6058875 -0.9193220`